# Can I call a subclass from a parent class to create the object

Tags: python, class, object, inheritance, subclass

For example:

```
class parent(self):
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i
    def something(self, value):
        a = child(value)
        return a

class child(parent):
    def something_that_is_not_init(self):
        return self.i
```

The child class inherits init from the parent class. So my question is, in my parent class, can I create an instance of the child object, use and return it?

I would execute it as following:

```
a = parent(2)
b = a.something(3)

b.something_that_is_not_init()
3
```

Edited question a bit, updated code section since the question wasn't clear.

Comment: This would be pretty bad OOP design. After all, `Child` already has a perfectly good way to instantiate it; why does `Parent` need such a method? Things having to do with each class should be contained within the class to which they apply.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: Thats what I thought, its for an assignment and it explicitly wanted one of the functions to return an instance of a child class. Edit: Actually, I may have made it look too simple in my question, there are other steps to be performed, other than creating it and returning it.

Comment: Any function or `__init__` itself? How do you know which child object to create?

Comment: The function and its description is given to us, and in the type contract it explicitly stated the return value should be an instance of the child class. Also the function does more than simply creating and returning it. I didn't post specifics since this is for a university class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's valid, but I don't recommend it. It's generally considered bad OOP programming. Also, you can create it as a static method so you never actually have to instantiate the parent class.

```
class parent():
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i

    @staticmethod
    def foo(i):
        c = child(i)
        return c

class child(parent):
    def bar(self):
        print("Lucker number {}.".format(self.i)) # just to show the parent __init__ function is called

c = parent.foo(7)
c.bar()  #=> Lucky number 7.
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your example (including some missing `self`) and with python3 at least it works:

```
class Parent():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def something(self):
        a = child()
        return a

class Child(parent):
    def something_that_is_not_init(self):
        print('yes, you got me')
```

and calling the `something` method works:

```
print(parent().something().__class__.__name__)
# Child
parent().something().something_that_is_not_init()
# yes, you got me
```

But maybe that's not very good design. Consider a factory or using `__new__`. But since you explicitly stated you wanted something like this: It works, even though I feel slightly spoiled writing it :-)